# In silverlight Date picker visibility changed while scrolling screen

Tags: silverlight-4.0

In silverlight Datepicker, I have set a property for changing Datepicker visibility. When creating new rows Datepickers are in visible state, but while scrolling its property changing automatically(become disabled state)